# If user would like to know which sites collection and their subsites (SPO) that one user can access, is there any way to check?

Tags: sharepoint-online

If user would like to know which sites collection and their subsites (SharePoint Online) that one user can access, is there any way to check?

Comment: Is this what you looking for?
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/93cb27/check-the-user-permissions-in-sharepoint-2013-online/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no OOB method to list the site collection and subsites that one user can access, you need to use code or Powershell to achieve your purpose.

Here is an article about "Get SharePoint Online Site and SubSites permission using PowerShell", which may be helpful to you:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Get-SharePoint-Online-and-7e6afce2

Check if the PowerShell commands in below article is useful to you:

[How to get a list of site/subsite users with permissions?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/234755/how-to-get-a-list-of-site-subsite-users-with-permissions)

Just for an example, you can also try to use Jquery. Reference:

[How to check one user's permissions for all sites/subsites in a site collection?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136581/how-to-check-one-users-permissions-for-all-sites-subsites-in-a-site-collection)